# Installing gcc-9 on Debian:stretch

Tags: debian, gcc

I'd like to install this version of gcc and g++ but in the official documentation it appears that no version >6 is supported ([link for official docs](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gcc-6)).
If not 9, then is it possible to install any version of gcc > 6?

Answer (score 1):

Debian stretch official repos only include gcc-6 (See [Release Notes for Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#gcc-versions)). If you want a newer version either you can add mirrors of a recent debian to the sources.list and use apt to install it or you can download and install it from https://gcc.gnu.org/ but be careful anyway for keeping your packages consistent.